# Obtener todos los campos de un documento de Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy usando un recyclerView para mostrar imagenes, para ello uso Glide,  tengo las url de las imagenes en un array,funciona bien.
Pero ahora quisiera obtener las url desde firebase, entonces para que sea mas facil he colocado todos los campos de las url en un mismo documento.

Obtengo un campo de esta manera.

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
db.collection("home").document("img").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Varss.imgOneurl = it.get("imgOneurl").toString()
            Varss.imgTwourl = it.get("imgTwourl").toString()
            
        }
```

Ahora quisiera poder obtener todos los campos de ese  documento "img" y agregarlos en un array

```
var x = 0
var a:String = "0"
var listimg = arrayListOf<String>()
db.collection("home").document("imgurl").get().addOnSuccessListener {
    while (x < 10){
        x++
        a = x.toString()
        listimg.add(it.get(a).toString())
    }
```

Ahora estoy intentando obtener un array, de la siguiente manera, cual es la forma correcta obtenerlo

```
var lista:ArrayList<String> = List<ArrayList>.it.get("img")
```

Comment: olvidaste decir que problema tienes con lo que intentaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un método `getData()` que retorna un `Map` de todos los campos del documento. Puedes convertirlo de la misma forma que conviertes cualquier map, por ejemplo:

```
db.collection("home").document("imgurl").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
    // esto es un arrayList
    val imageList = snapshot.data!!.map { it.value as String }
    // si estrictamente quieres que sea un array (Array<String>) agrega un toTypedArray()
    val images = imageList.toTypedArray()
}
```

Aunque lo mejor sería que ya lo subieras a firestore como array para evitar tener que hacer esto cada vez que lees el documento.

Comment: Gracias, por su sugerencia justo estuve investigando acerca de eso y al parecer es la mejor alternativa, ya que un array permitiría obtener varios datos y que se cuente como una sola lectura, sin embargo aun me quedan dudas respecto a eso. Podría explicarme que significa  
  "Profundidad máxima de los campos en un mapa o arreglo
en" 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields   
Esta justo al final de la sección indicada

Comment: No logro obtener el array , cual es el error.

-
var lista:ArrayList<String> = List<ArrayList>.it.get("img")

Comment: profundidad se refiere a la cantidad de niveles o dimensiones que tiene. Por ejemplo un array normal tiene una profundidad de 1. En cambio un array de arrays, que en kotlin sería  `Array<Array<*>>`, tiene una profundidad de 2. Y así sucesivamentemente. Otra forma de verlo es la cantidad de índices que necesitas para llegar al elemento más profundo. Por ejemplo si haces `myList[0][5][2][0]`, entonces tiene una profundidad de 4.

Comment: el error no lo entiendo. Agregalo a la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, por la aclaración de la profundidad, ya agregue  la forma como deseo obtener el array pero me da error..